# How do I re-render google map when props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-maps, react-hooks

I have an application in which I am using google maps. In the map component, I am drawing shapes and using coordinates and components passed by props to render the map and shapes on the map.

However, I want such that when the zones and coordinates change, the map should re-render. with the updated area map and shape.

When I add the zones and coordinates as array dependecies for the useEffect hook, I can see that the component re-render by logging to the console, but the google map does not.

Please, how do I go about this?

Has anyone implemented this before?

Do I have to call the "handleApiLoaded" function again?

My code is shown below.

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import useHeightPort from "../../Hooks/useHeightport";
import "../../assets/css/Map.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CreateSelect from "./CreateSelect";

import ZoneInfoWindow from "./ZoneInfoWindow";


import {
  createInfoWindow,
  drawPolygon,
  drawCircle,
  fitMapBounds,
  deepClone,
} from "./helpers"; /* I am using helper functions to tidy up things, not necessarily
integral to the apps functionality */

function Map({
  propZones,
  propCoords,
  propParticipants,
  showPLI
}) {
  
  let participants = deepClone(propParticipants); // get all from a single object here
  let [zones, setZones] = useState(deepClone(propZones));
  let [coords, setCoords] = useState(deepClone(propCoords));
  const [createDropdown, setCreateDropdown] = useState(<></>);

  const { Height } = useHeightPort();
  const calculatedHeight = Number(Height) - 289;

  const defaultProps = {
    center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    zoom: 0,
  };

  let globalMap, globalMaps;
  let shapeObjs = [];
  let activeZoneId = false;

  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setZones(deepClone(propZones));
    setCoords(deepClone(propCoords));

    console.log("Something changed");
  }, [propCoords, propZones /* zoneGroup_id, reshow */]);

  
  
    const handleApiLoaded = (map, maps) => {
    globalMap = map;
    globalMaps = maps;
     
    zones.forEach((zone, i) => {
      // Draw Shape
      let { shape, lat, lng } = drawShape(zone, coords[i]);

      // Add InfoWindow to Polygon
      let infoWindow = createIW(zone, lat, lng, shape);
      shape.addInfoWindow(infoWindow);
      shape.zone_id = zone.zone_id;

      shapeObjs.push(shape);
    });


    // Add Participants to Map
    if (participants) {
      let icon;
      let newMarkers = [];

      participants.forEach((p, i) => {
        icon = {
          url: p.image,
          //size: new maps.Size(40, 40),
          size: new mapds.Size(40, 40),
        };
        // let marker = new maps.Marker({
        let marker = new maps.Marker({
          position: { lat: p.lat, lng: p.lng },
          //map,
          map,
          icon,
          visible: showPLI,
          optimized: false,
        });

        // Create InfoWindow
        let pliInfoWindow = createPLIIW(marker, "Impossible", p);

        newMarkers.push({ marker, infoWindow: pliInfoWindow });
      });
      setMarkers(newMarkers);
    }

    
    fitMapBounds(maps, map, zones, coords, shapeObjs);
    

    setCreateDropdown(<CreateSelect drawNewShape={drawNewShape} />); // To create a new shap when the api is fully loaded
  };

 
  // Draw Shape
  function drawShape(zone, coord) {
    const shape =
      zone.shapeType === "polygon"
        ? drawPolygon(
            zone.id,
            globalMaps,
            globalMap,
            coord,
            zone.style,
            updateZoneCoordinates
          )
        : drawCircle(
            zone.id,
            globalMaps,
            globalMap,
            coord,
            zone.style,
            updateZoneCoordinates
          );

    let { lat, lng } =
      zone.shapeType === "polygon"
        ? coord[0]
        : { lat: coord.lat, lng: coord.lng };

    return { shape, lat, lng };
  }

  // Create InfoWindow
  function createIW(zone, lat, lng, shape) {
    // Create InfoWindow
    let infoDetails = {
      loc: zone.location,
      lat,
      lng,
    };
    let infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let infoContent = ReactDOM.render(
      ZoneInfoWindow(zone.id, zone.title, infoDetails),
      infoDiv
    );

    return createInfoWindow(infoContent, zone.id, globalMaps, {
      parent: shape,
      delete: deleteZone,
      edit: editZoneWithForm,
    });
  }

  // Draw new shape
  const drawNewShape = (type) => {
    let newZone = {
      id: zones.length + 1,
      title: "New Zone",
      location: "Atlanta, Georgia",
      shapeType: type,
      style: {
        strokeColor: "#0072ff",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
      },
    };
    let newCoord = drawDefaultShape(type);

    let { shape, lat, lng } = drawShape(newZone, newCoord);
    let infoWindow = createIW(newZone, lat, lng, shape);
    shape.addInfoWindow(infoWindow);

    shape.obj.setEditable(true);

    zones.push(newZone);
    coords.push(newCoord);
    shapeObjs.push(shape);

    if (activeZoneId !== false && activeZoneId !== newZone.id) {
      let activeZone = zones.find((z) => z.id === activeZoneId);
      shapeObjs[zones.indexOf(activeZone)].obj.setEditable(false);
    }

    activeZoneId = newZone.id;

    editZoneWithForm(newZone.id);
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="map-container" style={{ height: calculatedHeight + 159 }}>
      <div className="map-components" style={{ height: calculatedHeight - 70 }}>
        <div className="map-create-zone-container">{createDropdown}</div>
        
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "GOOGLE_API_KEY" }} // This will be turned to an Environment variable when we push live
          defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
          defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
          yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
          /* onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) =>
            handleApiLoaded.current(map, maps)
          } */
          onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => handleApiLoaded(map, maps)}
        ></GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: You will need to call `handleApiLoaded` again, as this is the only function which is rendering your static drawings.

Comment: Thanks @Stitt
Will I have to call again inside useEffect?
And how do Igo about that?

Comment: Where are you changing zones and coordinates? In the component that's consuming this one?

Comment: I would store your map & maps objects in a useState hook (if constant when moving the map) or re-fetch if these will change (but probably best to keep them in a useState in this case anyway). Then you can safely call handleApiLoaded in the same useEffect as your setZones() and setCoords() is in.

Comment: Thank you @yousoumar. I am changing from a parent component which has a dropdown showing all the zones.

Comment: Also thank you @Stitt.

I had to use a workaround by reloading the map component while setting the component to an empty fragment initially